# Добавление перевода строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Есть регулярка:

```
text = src.replace(/\<div class=""\>([\s\S]*)\<\/div\>/g, '$1');
```

Как сделать, чтобы после замены вставлялся перевод строки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить `\n` в конец:

```
text = src.replace(/\<div class=""\>([\s\S]*)\<\/div\>/g, '$1\n');
```

Comment: пробовал, не работает, и \r\n пробовал

Comment: А как вы смотрите ? В html \\n не отображается, попробуйте вместо \\n вставить `<br/>`

Comment: не, <br /> нельзя, делаю редактор, просто он сохраняет всё вписанное в одну строку, например <html><head>.... потом при новом редактировании в редакторе всё выглядит именно так: <html><head>....

Comment: Может, вы перед сохранением или выводом в редактор удаляете все "лишние" символы?

Comment: а как такая же регулярка с переводом строки на php будет выглядеть?

Comment: Почти так же:
    
    $text = str_replace('/<div class="">([\s\S]*)<\/div>/', "$1\n");

Comment: а вот символ | означает "или", а какой символ означает "и"?